# What are the terms for beats and a set of beats in a dance?

Tags: terminology, beats

I'm not native English speaking and not familiar with the technical terms in music. Thus this seems quite hard to Google an answer to...

In a dance, like a slow waltz, the count goes: `1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3...`.

What are the correct technical terms for one count, like a `1`, and for a set of counts that is repeated, like `1-2-3`?

I often hear people use the word `beat` at random to describe it all. In Danish the words `takt` and `taktslag` are used as far as I know, but I can't seem to find it in the dictionary when trying to translate to English.

What are actually the correct terms?

Comment: It may translate more directly to say "the music is in 3/4 _time_", although just stating "the music is in 3/4" also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the correct technical terms for one count, like a 1

It is simply called a [**beat**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_%28music%29).

> for a set of counts that is repeated, like 1-2-3?

`1-2-3` is a bar, so those three together could be called a bar. What might help you understand is called [**time signature**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_signature), which counts the beats of each bar.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Ok, how would you say the following: "The music is in 3/4...[what?]". I feel like I'm missing a word here - the Danish equivalent is simply `3/4-takt`, which apparently means `3/4 bar` (directly translated), but it doesn't sound right.

Comment: Actually, just saying that a song is `3/4` is enough. If you refer to the time signature link I posted above, you'll see what `3/4` means. The first image has this description: `three (3) quarter-notes (4) per measure.` So you can say to someone that a song is 3/4 and he'll understand

Comment: Ok, thanks. I understand the meaning, but was looking for the correct English term. Thank you very much and have a good week.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted formal term you are seeking is METRE (US English = METER). In ordinary language, the word "time" is more common. A waltz is said to be in "3/4 metre" (or time) or, alternatively, in "triple metre" (or time). For more, visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meter_(music)

Answer (score 1):

Both great answers,but there's also the RHYTHM of the bar that comes into the equation. Each bar in 3/4 or 4/4 etc. will have a distinctive rhythm pattern that  goes with a particular piece. Not all 4/4 songs have the same rhythm. For example, a simple 4/4 can have either a straight or a dotted rhythm, which makes each very different in FEEL.The tempo could be identical but the feel won't be.A 12/8 piece can be written with a 4/4 time signature for ease of writing (and reading) - although usually with a little note stated at the top.